# Etiquette: asking questioner to award bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have an answer posted on a question with a bounty. The bounty will expire in a few hours and no new answers have been posted in a few days. My answer currently stands to win the auto-accepted half bounty. My question is, can I ask the questioner to award me the full bounty, or is that wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the specific question or answer, I'd have to say in general that that would be wrong.  If the questioner had gotten the answer they needed, they probably would have awarded the bounty.  Remember that they still *lose* the full amount regardless of whether or not they *award* the full amount, so there's really no incentive for them to just let it expire.

Comment: Thanks, I'll hope they check in soon.